# why can not build sql server project on VS with this object

Tags: sql-server

If execute against database it works! but trying build on Vs sql server project it doesn't.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recebimento_Arquivo] (
    [RAr_Codigo]       INT                        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Rar_ID_FS]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER           DEFAULT (newid()) ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    [Rec_Codigo]       BIGINT                     NULL,
    [FAr_Codigo]       INT                        NOT NULL,
    [RAr_Arquivo]      VARBINARY (MAX) FILESTREAM NULL,
    [RAr_Dat_Cadastro] DATETIME                   CONSTRAINT [dnfRecebimentoArquivo_RArDatCadastro] DEFAULT (getdate()) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Recebimento_Arquivo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RAr_Codigo] ASC) ON [FG_ARQUIVOS_DADO],
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Recebimento_Arquivo_FAr_Codigo] FOREIGN KEY ([FAr_Codigo]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Formato_Arquivo] ([FAr_Codigo]),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Rar_ID_FS] ASC) ON [FG_ARQUIVOS_DADO]
) FILESTREAM_ON [FG_ARQUIVOS_FS_01];
```

It results

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       SQL71566: Filegroup: [FG_ARQUIVOS_FS_01] cannot not be set on both the Table: [dbo].[Recebimento_Arquivo] and the clustered Primary Key: [dbo].[PK_Recebimento_Arquivo].
```

Comment: Clustered index/key is table itself - most likely you cannot set filegroup for it separately at all.

Comment: if I just omit filegroup on primary key it work, but need understand why expliciting filegroup on primary it doesn't work!

Comment: Problem is not primary, but clustered key. Clustered key is data (table) itself and it cannot be located in another filegroup than table one (they are the same data) - and likely sql server doesn't allow to set it in this case at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, looks to be a bug in VS SQL Server projects.

As other comments say, you cannot speecify different filegroups for clustered key and for table. But that's not what you do. The final filegroup specification is for the filestream data that you store in the varbinary(max) column. Based on the syntax description in Books Online, this should be valid - and the fact that this runs when you execute it on SQL Server directly confirms that.

Comment: Is true this is a bug in Visual Studio to solve my problem in my project what I did was just omit the FileGroup in my primary key and the project compiled normally

Answer (score 0):

Ans is in your error itself,

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       SQL71566: Filegroup: [FG_ARQUIVOS_FS_01] cannot not be set on both the Table: [dbo].[Recebimento_Arquivo] and the clustered Primary Key: [dbo].[PK_Recebimento_Arquivo].
```

you need to have different FileGroup and Primary Key Identifier.

Comment: They are differents!

Comment: check other tables

Comment: They are differents! Table filegroup is  FILESTREAM_ON [FG_ARQUIVOS_FS_01], and Primary key filegroup is [FG_ARQUIVOS_DADO].